# Why isn't Coldfusion/Batik rendering my custom fonts?

Tags: coldfusion, fonts, batik

Under CF9, I'm converting SVGs to PNGs using the Batik (1.7) transcoder. The SVGs contain text using non-standard fonts which I've installed under Windows on the server, but which are being replaced with fallback system fonts during the Batik conversion. I've tried both TTF and OTF fonts and the suggestions here: http://webmonkeyswithlaserbeams.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/custom-fonts-in-coldfusion/. Embedding the fonts in the SVGs isn't a viable option due to parsing performance problems in another area of the application.

Comment: Have you installed the font under Server Settings > Font Management in your CF Administrator?

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that the fonts are in the "Current System Fonts" list there.

Comment: Have you tried using the exact font name listed there?

Comment: Yep, I've tried both the Family and and Face values with no change.

Comment: might wanna resort to http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/mailing-lists.html

Comment: maybe u need to use their SVG Font Converter

Comment: I was able to get better results by resorting to ImageMagick commands instead of Batik for the conversion, though YMMV.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to embed the svg font definations inside your svg. There is no other way.

Comment: These links I found say "There is, too!" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993130/svg-to-png-text-not-showing-properly-arial-font/17993932#17993932 http://batik.2283329.n4.nabble.com/Batik-1-7-Transcoder-Chinese-Font-td2977384.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that Batik renders fonts well if you specify a font-family in your SVG that is registered with the Grahpics environment.

Unregistering, however, does not seem to work.

Ticket: [Unregister font with GraphicsEnvironment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523648/unregister-font-with-graphicsenvironment)