# SVG to PNG text not showing properly - Arial font

Tags: svg, png, transcoding, batik

I'm having an issue of converted PNG using Apache Batik is different when there is a text with different font-family, like Arial. The issue occurs in the environment where Cent OS 6 running Tomcat 7 and Java 6.

The Java code used to convert SVG to PNG is :

```
// Convert the SVG image to png and send back
PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();
// 
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(svgImage));
outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outStream);

// Transcode the given SVG
transcoder.transcode(input, output);

outStream.flush();

pngImage = outStream.toByteArray();
```

The SVG file I am going to convert to PNG is :

```
<svg version="1.1" x="0" y="0" id="hjtqebzv1" width="610" height="240" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="LFFFFFF0" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.8"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#FAFAFA;stop-opacity:1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="hjtqebzv-o1" transform="translate(5,5)">
      <rect x="1" y="1" width="578" height="20" fill="url(#LFFFFFF0)" stroke="#5e5ca7" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"/>
      <text x="1" y="1" width="578" height="19" >
        <tspan x="2" y="14" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;fill:#000000;">This is a test text for testing text overlapping in the rectangle when convert the svg to PNG using SVG-Batik</tspan>
      </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When I open the SVG file in Firefox browser it displays properly as given in the below image :
[image]

But when I convert the SVG using Apache Batik, the converted image looks different. The Apache Batik converted PNG is:
[image]

In the Windows 7 running tomcat 7 and Java 7, the generated image is identical to the original SVG.

As the Cent OS server it gives the text messed image I feel the Arial font is not available to the tomcat/java application and need to load it manually. If so I prefer to have an advice to load them in a common way from the underlying OS location (OS font location) without any changes to the SVG file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Microsoft truetype fonts and make them available to java virtual machine by setting `JAVA_FONTS` environment variable.

```
wget http://www.my-guides.net/en/images/stories/fedora12/msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
```

Open `/etc/bashrc` and add following to the end of the file

```
JAVA_FONTS=/usr/share/fonts/msttcore

export JAVA_FONTS
```

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-microsoft-truetype-fonts-in-centos-6-rhel-6.html#axzz2aibHZaOI