# Java- load only fonts from jre/lib/fonts

Tags: java, awt

Java runtime adds fonts from system to its GraphicsEnvironment.  Oracle/Sun documentation on fontconfig.properties [is here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html). These explain how to add fonts to Java.

I am looking for restricting the font loading(testing).  Unloading a loaded font is not straightforward (discussed here [Unregister font with GraphicsEnvironment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523648/unregister-font-with-graphicsenvironment))

Is there a way to restrict java to load fonts listed in jre/lib folder?

Answer (score 1):

Specify empty `sun.java2d.fontpath` property to prevent from loading system fonts.

```
  java -Dsun.java2d.fontpath= -jar YourApp
```